# suggestion where to look to find why my report has extra blank pages

Tags: ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder, microsoft-reporting

I am on Msoft SQL Server Report Builder, v15.0
I have a multi page report that no matter that forces a blank page every 2nd page.

I have searched through the tablix properties, report properties, header & footer properties and have not found a culprit yet.
I fear that there are somehow some hidden pieces that are causing this issue, but I do not know how to be able to see the hidden pieces.

I have opened the .rdl file up in notepad++ and started walking through the code, but I am not certain where I should look at in there that would cause my problem.
It is a 10 column report that is generated from a dataset culled down, but the report has 3 calculated fields in it, including a column which generates a ranking number.

If you know of a explicit piece of code I should search for that would be awesome, but I know that is a needle in a snowpile.....

Answer (score 0):

Found finally what I had done...

my durn body was the same width as the page sheet so it was pushing the margins off and creating a new page.
Here is a good walk through of what I found.....
http://www.keepitsimpleandfast.com/2009/12/export-of-reporting-server-reports-to.html